# How to Implement CNN2D+ LSTM Model For Image Classification in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, conv-neural-network

There is 2550 images as train set and 1530 images as test set. to classify these images into two classes, a hybrid deep learning model including CNN2D+LSTM is used but there is an error is occurred during running the code as is shown below. i was wonder if someone help me to solve it. thanks in advance

ERROR:

> RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it

```
# importing libraries
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                                    rescale=1./255,
                                    shear_range=0.2,
                                    zoom_range=0.2,
                                    horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                    'D:\\thesis\\Paper 3\\Feature Extraction\\two_dimension_Feature_extraction\\stft_feature\\Training_set',
                                    target_size=(64, 64),
                                    batch_size=32,
                                    class_mode='binary')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                    'D:\\thesis\\Paper 3\\Feature Extraction\\two_dimension_Feature_extraction\\stft_feature\\Test_set',
                                    target_size=(64, 64),
                                    batch_size=32,
                                    class_mode='binary')

#initializing the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

#convolution2D
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32,3,3, input_shape = (64,64,3), activation = 'relu'))) #32 feature detector with 3*3 dimensions, 64*64 is the used format with 3 channel because the image is colored

#adding maxpooling 
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(2, 2)))
#Flattening
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

classifier.add(TimeDistributed(classifier))
classifier.add(LSTM(units= 20, input_shape = (1,5), return_sequences = True ))
classifier.add(LSTM(units = 20))

#Full Connection
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

#compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

#Fitting the CNN to the images

history = classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch=2550,
                         epochs=25,
                         validation_data= test_set,
                         validation_steps=510)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'r', label='Training acc')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'b', label='Validation acc')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.figure()
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'r', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.plot()
plt.legend()
plt.show()

test_loss, test_acc = classifier.evaluate(test_set)
print('test_acc:', test_acc)
```

Comment: Can you pl share your Tensorflow Keras version????